# Is there a tool to automatically convert a make file to sln/vcproj?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, makefile

Google reveals many tools for taking Visual Studio format sln/vcproj files, and producing a make file from them. But I can't find one that solves the opposite problem - I have a make file that references hundreds of .c and .h files and (for convenience, for debugging, for writing code in the VS IDE) would like to open it as a Visual Studio project.

Where can I find a tool to take an arbitrary make file as input, and produce Visual Studio project/solution files as output?

Answer (score 3):

[Makefile Project Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y48z24a.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find a converter for a well-constrained set of makefiles, but a converter for any arbitrary makefile would be tricky. They are mini-programs, after all, that would have to be evaluated. And not all makefile concepts map directly to Visual Studio projects.

If you only have one project to worry about, I'd just manually put together a project in Visual Studio (tip: you can select more than one file in the "Add existing file..." dialog). If you do this regularly, perhaps look into a tool like Premake or CMake to help automate the generation of the projects (and if necessary, a new Makefile) for you.