# Is there a way to convert omake build to ms build

Tags: tfs, msbuild, clearcase, omake

I would like to convert omake projects (clearcase) to msbuild (TFS). Please let me know whether any tool is available for the conversion. I would appricate if you have give me an example

Answer (score 1):

[`omake` project](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_omake.htm) is a Rational® ClearCase® utility to build, maintain, update, and regenerate groups of programs. It includes many of the configuration management facilities provided by the `clearmake` utility.

> [`omake`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/omake.htm) is intended for use in dynamic views. You can use `omake` in a snapshot view, but none of the features that distinguish it from ordinary make programs (build avoidance, build auditing, derived object sharing, and so on) works in snapshot views

I don't think TFS would offer workspaces running like a dynamic view, or orffering similar clearmake-like features like DO and winkins.

So there isn't any conversion possible to my knowledge: those projects becomes simple make/Makefile projects once migrated in their new TFS referential.

---

Regarding the more general issue of converting a Makefile to a `.sln` file, [that old question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1849416/6309) mentioned the [Makefile Project Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y48z24a.aspx), also mentioned [in this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/999770c9-931a-4356-a00e-c23a380e5ec7/makefile-and-sln-vs-2010?forum=vcgeneral) and in [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txcwa2xx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> If you have a project that you build from the command line with a makefile, then the Visual Studio development environment will not recognize your project.
>   To open and build your project using Visual Studio, first create an empty project containing the appropriate build settings using the **Makefile Project Wizard**.
>   You can then use this project to build your project from the Visual Studio development environment.

Comment: thanks for the comment. i understand your point. omake uses Makefile. I would like to convert Makefiles to .sln file. so it is easy to work with Visual Studio.