# Omake Utility for SVN in Perl scripts

Tags: perl, svn, clearcase, omake

I have to make some builds for SVN using the Perl scripting, the scripts are originally for Clearcase builds. I have come across an utility "omake". Can any give example of how can I use it for subversion?

The command in the script is 
system "omake $MakeTarget $Processor" where $MakeTarget is calling another script which makes the maketarget.bat file and $Processor is the processor it should call.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in "[What is the svn equivalent to winkin in clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32762932/6309)", you cannot "translate" omake, which apply in a very specific ClearCase context (dynamic view with DO -- derived object -- in order to not recompile everything")

[Its documentation (`omake`)](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/topics/a_omake.htm?lang=en) includes:

> omake is intended for use in dynamic views.
>   **You can use `omake` in a snapshot view, but none of the features that distinguish `omake` from ordinary `make` programs**, such as build avoidance, build auditing, derived object sharing, and so on, works in snapshot views.

In your case, you can simply replace `omake` with `make`.
(a bit like for "[Is there a way to convert `omake build` to `ms build`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25285079/6309)")